# android : Firebase Firestore not working api 17

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an android app that contains Firebase firestore
When the app  is run on devices less than 21 apu, no data is sent or received from the server
But when running an app on 21 api versions it works without any problems?

Comment: Can you provide some logs or error messages that may give insight into the problem?  This is not enough info to go on.

Comment: When adding data there is no error but the code is not executed

Comment: I was seeing the same thing on API 26. The database was not changing but there were no errors. I created a completely new AVD and updated play services; what actually fixed it I have no idea, but it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the official documentation! The Firebase API is only supported with Android SDK version 21 or above. And Material Design is also only supported the SDK version 21 or above.

(I assume you’re new to Android, which is why I also mention Material Design; if you use it in the future, then you won’t have a problem.)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation you’re referring to? That would be useful.